# Fastest way to communicate between applications on single container

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, wildfly

I have to applications running on a single `Wildfly` container using single database. Currently they are communicated with each other using `JAX-RS` and I wonder is there more faster way?

What I have already found:

- JAX-RS
- [Local EJB](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/inter-app)
- [Remote EJB](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/ejb-multi-server)
- JMS

Seems that the most fastest way is to use *Local EJB*. But I am not sure about *JMS*. And what about *Websockets*?

Comment: Speed/Performance will only be measured by the likes of the amount of data being sent and the number of concurrent users.

Comment: Probably I should reformulate my question to the list of possible ways of the communication with their pros and cons...

Comment: Way, way, waaaaaay too broad a question

Answer (score -1):

Ok, one could complain about the question being too broad formulated but providing one possible answer would also be nice ;)

So here is my suggestion:
Simply create a clean API for the communication between the modules and deploy it as a JAR to your server. The module that contains the JAX-RS endpoint could also implement the API to provide the services you need (not only for internal usage but also for your REST service which then would simply delegate the request processing). Now you can simply inject a service using CDI when you need it for internal usage and as far as I know this is the fastest possible way to go for internal communication since it works directly with JAVA objects. Using CDI for the injection of the service implementation has also the benefit of decoupling the modules.

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: I asked not about modules, but about separate applications (`war` files). Actually I want to here pros\cons of communication via JAX-RS, RMI, something else

Comment: why can't applications communicate internally through API calls? If you define an API that describes the service of your application, another application deployed on the same machine can use this API to call the service implementation. And this is much faster than calling a service throught http.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/inter-app (communication via local interface ejbs) ?

Comment: I just had a short glance on it and it seems to be something like what I mean, yes. You will have to set jboss module dependencies between the apps and the api, ... and then everything should work using injection. This is the way we go and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at memory-mapped files? They can offer some [very high throughput](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2013/04/lock-free-ipc-queue.html). Check out the NIO [FileChannel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) class. For a ready-to-run solution, take a look at [Jocket](https://github.com/pcdv/jocket).